# join lines in a text file python

Tags: python, file

This is really basic but for some reason I am struggling with it

I have a file f.txt that has the following contents

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

I want the output to be `"abc"OR"def"OR"ghi"OR"jkl"`
This is what I have tried

```
join = ""
with open("f.txt") as f:
 for line in f:
   join = "\""+line.rstrip()+"OR\""+join
f.close()
print join[:-2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with ... as f:
   " or ".join(f.read().split())
```

if your input is really as simple as you show

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("f.txt") as inf:
    items = ('"{}"'.format(line.strip()) for line in inf)
    join = "OR".join(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
   print 'OR'.join(['\"%s\"' % line[:-1] for line in f])
```